# Silent .NET Framework on WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.7, wix3.6

I have a WiX installer and, as part of the installation process, I'm installing the offline .NET Framework installer.

```
<ExePackage Id = "DotNetFramework.Setup" SourceFile="..\DotNetFramework\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" />
```

Is there any way to install it in silent mode?

Every solution I find tell to launch msiexec specifying the parameters, for example:

```
msiexec /i product.msi APPLICATIONFOLDER="C:\Program Files\Company\Product\"
```

but my `ExePackage` just asks for the `SourceFile`, not a proper command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExePackage element has an InstallCommand attribute, where you can specify the silent flag. For example:

```
<ExePackage
    Id="SomeId"
    InstallCommand="/norestart /q"
    SourceFile="SomeFile.exe" />
```

For more information about .Net Framework Installation flags, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers